# Как сделать жирный цвет в сообщении телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telebot, шрифты, бот, telegram

Делаю через `parse_mode="Markdown"`, но у меня в ссылке на есть нижнее подчеркивание

```
('_Запись на консультацию_ по контактам  @ron_pozharyts',  parse_mode="Markdown")
```

выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Пару вариантов решения вашего вопроса:

**1.** Использовать **parse_mode="Markdown"** и экранировать `_` обратным слешем `\` в нике

> ('*****Запись на консультацию по контактам***** @ron\_pozharyts',
> parse_mode="Markdown")

**2.** Использовать **parse_mode="MarkdownV2"** и так же экранировать `_` обратным слешем `\` в нике, но тут жирным будет писаться и ник в том числе

> ('*****Запись на консультацию по контактам @ron\_pozharyts*****',
> parse_mode="MarkdownV2")

**3.** Либо же использовать **parse_mode="HTML"**, завернув свой текст, который нужно сделать жирным в **<b>** **</b>**

> ('<b>Запись на консультацию по контактам @ron_pozharyts</b>',
> parse_mode="HTML")